# Passing variable parameter-lists to threads in own thread-pool engine

Tags: c++

I want to modify my thread-pool engine so that I can pass different parameter-lists to the threads; just like I can start a std::thread with different parameter-lists. So how do I pack this parameter lists and hand them over to the thread ? Some example-code would be nice.

Comment: *Some example-code would be nice.* Aboslutely! Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. This is not a code writing service. Show what you tried and why it's not working. Also, you specifically want to modify your thread-pool. You don't think it's relevant to show the code for your thread pool... ??

Comment: Of course it's usual here that people here help others with code-examples.